# Manual NPM update in Phoenix

Tags: npm, elixir, asset-pipeline, phoenix-framework, assets

Currently, I am working on an application using the Phoenix framework. When I start the application with `mix phx.server` it seems that the assets are usually not automatically updated. Usually I fix this problem by navigating into the `assets` subdirectory, delete the `node_modules` directory and then execute `npm install`.

I would expect this to happen automatically. What could be the reason for the need for manual intervention?

My platform is Debian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch), Elixir 1.6.5 and Erlang/OTP 21 installed by packages provided by Erlang Solutions, Node 7.10.1 and NPM 4.2.0 provided by packages from NodeSource. Using Phoenix 1.3.

Comment: I assume you have the inotify package installed?

Comment: Are you talking about an Erlang or Elixir package? Or are you thinking about the Linux kernel API?

Comment: I'm talking about the linux package. It's needed for the live reload feature (https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_reload).